# mutating table ORA-04091 oracle(trying to deny update on condition)

Tags: oracle, triggers

I'm trying to rewrite the trigger so it doesn't give a mutating table (ORA-04091)error. The table and trigger  definition are as follows (commented part of the trigger giving the mutating table exception )

```
CREATE TABLE "COPYREAL"."PL_EDUCPLANS" 
   (    "PLANID" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "STUDYFORM" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SKILLCODE" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "YEARBEGIN" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SPECCODE" VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SEMESTERS" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "BIFURCATE_SEMESTER" NUMBER(2,0), 
    "CHAIRID" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "LESS10" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "CURATOR_CHAIR" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "SCHOOL_DISCS" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "MARKSYSTEMID" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SKILL" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "VKR_WEEKS" NUMBER(2,0), 
    "TOTALHOURS_GOS" NUMBER(5,0), 
    "NORM_LEARN_TIME" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "SKILL_ENG" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "FIS_ITEM_UID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "TOTALCOST" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "TOTALCOST_STR" VARCHAR2(800 CHAR), 
    "FORWP" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ISOLD" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "COMMENTARY" VARCHAR2(500 CHAR), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_PL_EDUCPLANS" PRIMARY KEY ("PLANID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_PL_EDUCPLANS_CHAIRID" FOREIGN KEY ("CHAIRID")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."RB_DEPARTMENTS" ("CODE") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_CURATORCHAIR_DEP" FOREIGN KEY ("CURATOR_CHAIR")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."RB_DEPARTMENTS" ("CODE") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_PL_EDUCPLANS_RB_SKILLS" FOREIGN KEY ("SKILLCODE")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."RB_SKILLS" ("CODE") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_PL_EDUCPLANS_RB_SPECS" FOREIGN KEY ("SPECCODE")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."RB_SPECIALITY" ("CODE") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_PL_EDUCPLANS_RB_STUDYFORMS" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDYFORM")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."RB_STUDYFORMS" ("CODE") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_PLEDUCPLANS_SCMARKSYSTEMS" FOREIGN KEY ("MARKSYSTEMID")
      REFERENCES "COPYREAL"."SC_MARKSYSTEMS" ("MARKSYSTEMID") ENABLE
   );
```

The trigger is:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "COPYREAL".tr_pl_educplans
before insert or update or delete
on pl_educPlans
for each row
DECLARE
   l_flag NUMBER(1);
begin
 IF :NEW.FORWP = 0 THEN
  if inserting or updating then 

  delete from pl_processed_plans where planid=:new.planid;

   DELETE FROM PL_PROCESSED_PLANS_B WHERE PLANID=:NEW.PLANID;

  /* select case when exists(
       SELECT 1 
        FROM PL_EDUCPLANS EP 
                where EP.FORWP=0 AND EP.YEARBEGIN=:NEW.YEARBEGIN AND EP.STUDYFORM=:NEW.STUDYFORM AND ep.SKILLCODE=:NEW.SKILLCODE and ep.SPECCODE=:NEW.SPECCODE
     ) then 1 else 0 end
     into l_flag from Dual;

     IF L_FLAG = 1 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Plan exists!');
     end if;
  */

  end if;

  if deleting then
     delete from pl_processed_plans where planid=:old.planid;

     delete from pl_processed_plans_b where planid=:old.planid;

     delete from pl_plan_activities_mt where planid=:old.planid;

     delete from pl_plan_activities_b where planid=:old.planid;
  END IF;
   end if;
end;
```

insert runs as it should (giving the exception "plan exists"  when trying to insert the duplicate value for a regular plan), that is once you run the update on the table (obvously you cannot select from tje same table that fired the trigger in the first place)

basically what I am trying to achieve here is to enforce the following business logic
you cannot have 2 **regular** plans(the plan is considered regular when it has forwp attribute value of 0)) that have the same studyform,skillcode,speccode and yearbegin values for each other  and you can have as many as you want irregular plans  that have the same studyform,skillcode,speccode and yearbegin values for each other.
an irregular plan (the plan is considered irrregular when it has forwp attribute value of 1)
before the introduction of the forwp attribute the previous business logic was enforced by  a unique constraint(studyform,skillcode,speccode,yearbegin ) on the pl_educplans table and I'm not too sure how to enforce the rule now 
I've read the suggestions  given on https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions but I'm not sure how to apply them to my case

is enforcing such business logic rule even possible with a trigger? or should such check  be done on the application level?

Comment: The cleanliest solution would be to discard the triggers, create specific DML procedures, put all the business logic there and use this new API in your application (for future projects). Mediocre solution would be to create a validation procedure (DB) and call it in application, right before DML procedure. Oracle itself mentioned several times, don't enforce business logic in triggers.

Comment: If you don't mind changing your data model, you could also switch from using `forwp=1` to indicate irregular plans to using `forwp = a unique non-zero integer sequence` - then you could go back to using your unique constraint.